# How can I convert "2020-04-10T18:46:42+08:00" to "18:46" in Swift?

Tags: swift, date, swift4.1

How can I convert "2020-04-10T18:46:42+08:00" to "18:46" in Swift?

I try to format this but I can't find a better solution.

Comment: Have you checked https://nsdateformatter.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Function

```
let getDate = "2020-04-10T18:46:42+08:00"
let x = self.dateInRequiredFormat(stringDate: getDate, requiredFormat : "HH:mm")
print("date:- \(x)")
```

Function for date formatting

```
 func dateInRequiredFormat(stringDate:String, requiredFormat:String)->String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    let checkInDateStr = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = requiredFormat
    let dateInRequiredFormat = dateFormatter.string(from: checkInDateStr)
    return dateInRequiredFormat
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That also a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Calendar` class `component(_:from:)` method to get an hour and minutes.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.component(.hour, from: date) // hour
calendar.component(.minute, from: date) // minute
```